# Adjust lock_timeout parameter in AWS RDS PostgreSQL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Question:
Is it possible to Adjust `lock_timeout` parameter in AWS RDS PostgreSQL?

What information I have:

- PosgreSQL engine version: 12.8
- Based on [official docks](https://Adjust%20lock_timeout%20parameter%20in%20AWS%20RDS%20PostgreSQL) RDS for PostgreSQL DB instance parameter list doesn't have this parameter, but table showing parameters units (At the end of the docs page) shows that default unit for this parameter is `ms`. So I'm confused a little bit. Also [postgreSQL docs](https://postgresqlco.nf/doc/en/param/lock_timeout/) says that this parameter is available from version 9.3
- Search this parameter in parameter group also give me no results (so looks like it's one of AWS limitations)

What I tried:

- Manual search in DB parameter group (no results)
- Updating parameter in parameter group with terraform (Error: parameter not found)
- Updating parameter in parameter group with aws-cli (Error: parameter not found, as exepted)

What I don't want to do:

- Update parameter with SQL query, because I'm wondering about consistency between real BD parameters and IAC files (we're using terraform). So, if I update parameter with query, and after that reboot instance or upgrade it, RDS apply parameter group without `lock_timeout` (Correct me if I'm wrong)